# Edited links are too hard to see in the Suggested Edits review queue

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, hyperlinks

There is no way to visually distinguish edited regular text from edited links in the Suggested Edits review queue: both appear as dark-grey-on-green.

Here's a screenshot illustrating the issue:

[image]

In the above post, the two pastebin.com links that appear as regular text on the left have been formatted into proper links, which you can follow by clicking on "this" and "this". However, just from looking at it you can't tell that "this" is a link because it looks the same as regular edited text, so at a glance it looks like the pastebin links have just been deleted. To verify that they are there and correctly formatted you have to mouse-over all the edited words to find them, which is kind of a hassle and wouldn't be possible on a touch device. Granted it's fairly obvious where they are likely to be from the context, but I think it could be made easier.

Is it possible to change the formatting so that edited links appear with a different text or background color, or are underlined?

Also, could a list of referenced URLs be displayed underneath the edited post?

Comment: View the Markdown diff is the usual way to detect changes like this.

Comment: @nhahtdh Ok, that works for a case like the above where I notice a link seems to have disappeared and I want to check if it is still there. But what if a brand new link has been added? I wouldn't even notice its existence unless I view the markdown diff as my default because it would appear just like a regular edit.

Comment: I would suggest switching this feature request to asking for brand-new links to switch to Markdown diff like other URL changes do.