# URLs in edit reviews are rendered as live links, even without any markdown formatting

Tags: bug

I was reviewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14972730)  edit suggestion just now. The edit comment is *"Made nltk.org link clickable"*.

But the link in the original version is highlighted blue. *"That's odd..."* says I, *"... the link is **already** clickable"*. Sure enough, if I hover over it, my cursor changes and I can see the target at the bottom of the screen:

[image]

If I open the original question in another tab, however, I can see that the link is indeed not clickable (as expected).

So. This looks like a bug: URLs in edit reviews are rendered as live links, even without any markdown formatting. 
I accept that it's not a terribly problematic bug, but it could lead to robo-reviewers unfairly rejecting the edit as "No Improvement Whatsoever"

Related, but not an exact dupe: [Edited links are too hard to see in the Suggested Edits review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294785/edited-links-are-too-hard-to-see-in-the-suggested-edits-review-queue)

Comment: Presumably, bare URLs of that form weren't linkified at the time the answer was first posted, but now are. Since post diffs are *always* rendered in real-time, I'm not sure this sort of thing can be fixed.

Comment: @BoltClock that could explain [this mysterious bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231328/a-suggested-edit-was-submitted-without-any-changes) (not URL rendering specifically, but the rendered output being different without any markdown changes)

Comment: @BoltClock Oh. That makes sense, I suppose. I didn't know that they are linkified now.

Comment: This still looks like an improvement to me, even if the original link *was* clickable. An even better choice would have been to make the text itself ("The Natural Language Toolkit") the link.

Comment: @CodyGray: I agree, I approved this edit (or at least cast my vote to approve it).